# KeyError when importing a CSV to SQLite using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, gtfs

I'm very (very) new to python and coding in general and I am trying to import GTFS (.txt) in SQLITE db using python. I keep getting a KeyError on the field "trip_id" but the code works well when I am using other columns of the table (stop_times, in this case). I think I understand how to handle KeyError but I just don't get why it doesn't want to import the column as it is defined in the dictionnary... Here my code below :

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("GTFS.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE stop_times (stop_id INTEGER, trip_id TEXT);")

with open('stop_times.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as dic:
    dr = csv.DictReader(dic)
    db_sqlite = [(i['stop_id'], i['trip_id']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO stop_times (stop_id, trip_id) VALUES (?, ?);", db_sqlite)

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Here's an overview of the stop_times table, in case you are not familiar with GTFS format. Thanks for your help!

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence,stop_headsign,pickup_type,drop_off_type,shape_dist_traveled,timepoint
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:45:00,06:45:00,4416,0,Windsor,0,1,0,1
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:46:07,06:46:07,3685,551,Windsor,0,0,551,0
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:47:05,06:47:05,1015,1022,Windsor,0,0,1022,0
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:47:34,06:47:34,1016,1263,Windsor,0,0,1263,0
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:47:56,06:47:56,1017,1443,Windsor,0,0,1443,0
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:48:36,06:48:36,1018,1771,Windsor,0,0,1771,0
1_1_R_DI_1601_06_45,06:49:00,06:49:00,1019,1961,Windsor,0,0,1961,1
```

Comment: The code and sample input doesn't give any KeyError. Can you find any sample that does give a KeyError?

Comment: Weird..! It works with the sample for me as well. However, it keep showing a KeyError on trip_id with the whole set of data (320 000 lines) but it doesn't with other columns... I went throught trip_id and everything seems to be find with the data. Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Doesn't the KeyError have to be coming from this line `db_sqlite = [(i['stop_id'], i['trip_id']) for i in dr]`?

Comment: The KeyError seems to be coming from "trip_id" when using the whole set of data but it works fine when I use the sample above or biggest sample of the database.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the `stop_times.txt` file that the program is reading does not have a column heading `trip_id` in the first line.

Comment: Well. It certainly does. The weird thing is that it perfectly works when I try to upload a smaller number of lines, but it shows a KeyError or simply doesn't load the data in SQLite when trying with the whole set of data. If I import the data into SQLite manually, it works...

Comment: Is there some problem with the last line in your file. Is there one? Perhaps there shouldn't be one.